# How to add ChargifyNET as a dependency to a TeamCity project?

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

We have recently switched to TeamCity 7.1.4 for our automated build system and attempting to add [ChargifyNET](http://chargify.codeplex.com/) dependency to an existing project. I have read up on the [Build Artifact concept](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Artifact) and the [Dependent Build concept](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Dependent+Build) and they both seem pretty straight forward. However, the documentation really isn't clear on how to [add a dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD4/Configuring+Dependencies) that you do not need to build/compile.

Ideally, I would like to store the archive containing the ChargifyNET binaries in a folder and be able to reference that archive as an artifact when configuring dependencies for my project. How can I set this up?

So far, I've configured a separate project for ChargifyNET and declared the individual binaries from the archive as artifacts for this project (for example, %teamcity.agent.work.dir%/Chargify.NET/1.0.7/ChargifyNET.dll). Then I added a dependency to the main project for the ChargifyNET project artifacts.

When I build the main project I get a "Artifacts resolving failed" error. In the build log, under "Resolving artifact dependencies" I see no mention of the ChargifyNET artifacts.

How can I add ChargifyNET as a dependency to a TeamCity project? Do I need to get into a custom Ant script or can this be done from the UI?

Maybe the issue is with the artifact paths. Should 3rd party libraries be stored under the agent work directory or some other folder?

Is it best practice to have all 3rd party libraries checked in to a VCS repository? Perhaps a different solution would be to add an additional VCS root to the main project that points to the VCS repository holding 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the Chargify.NET project as mentioned in the question was on track.

1. Create a build configuration under this project and enter a static build number (i.e. 1.0.7).
2. You have to "Run" the Chargify.NET build so TeamCity will create a dynamic build folder for it in the agent work directory.
3. Copy the Chargify.NET binaries into the folder created in step#2.
4. Modify the artifact path(s) from "%teamcity.agent.work.dir%/Chargify.NET/1.0.7/ChargifyNET.dll" to just "ChargifyNET.dll". This new path should refer directly to the files mentioned in step#3.
5. Modify the artifact path(s) in the Build Dependencies section of the main project to for Chargify.NET. They should look the same as in step#4 except that you may want to add a destination path (like so "ChargifyNET.dll=>trunk/bin").
6. Build the main project and you should see the files importing correctly.